# How to read the EA.Element order in the project browser

Tags: enterprise-architect

Using Add-In we are creating EA Elements in some random alphabetical order.

The sequence for EA elements in the project browser is shown in the below figure:
[image: EA Element in project browser]

While fetching the EA Elements using the below mentioned code, the sequence is: a, c, D, E, g, H, J, B, f, i (B, f, i is of type Enumeration class and others are of type Class).

```
for (short k = 0; k < getElement.Elements.Count; k++)
{   
  EA.Element dataTypeEle = getElement.Elements.GetAt(k);
}
```

But the required output should be as per EA Elements sequence present in the Project browser as shown in the above figure.

How can we read EA Elements as per the sequence present in the project browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EA.Element.Treepos` contains the position in the project browser.

If that is all 0, or does not correspond with the order you are seeing then it might be that you have the option not to allow free sorting in the project browser on, which means everything is ordered alphabetically  like set the underlying database (there can be tricky settings with umlaut etc.).

In that case you'll have to use the name to sort the collection.

Another thing is that EA has a strange way of grouping element types (such as diagrams, packages, elements, enumerations) which is probably hardcoded somewhere in the EA code, but it is always the same. So if you can't use Treepos then you'll have to figure it out yourself using the name and the grouping EA uses.

Comment: @ Geert: Thanks for the reply.
Fetching the EA Elements is working fine when Treepos value has been set, but there is not impact of Treepos on Project browser, still the EA Elements in the Project browser is displayed in the stored order.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: @Greet: will the elements in the project browser will be displayed based on treepos value or based on alphabetical order

Comment: The project browser order per se is Sparxish! It also sorts out diagrams, packages and a couple of other things. Don't try to guess it! It is absolutely confusing. And EA does not offer anything to give you the shown order.

Comment: That depends on your settings. There is a setting that control free sorting in the project browser. (you'll notice green up/down arrows if you have free sorting on). Next to that there's the grouping per type that plays a role. PS. "Greet" is a female name in where I come from, please take the effort to spell my name correctly.

Comment: @GeertBellekens: Sorry for the typing mistake.